# broken link avatar image

Tags: support, gravatar

So I must get this out of my chest. ;-)
Why do so many people have a broken image symbol as avatar image ?

Do they provide broken image link ? Or is it askubuntu ?
Can this be fixed ?

Isn't this has to do with the default avatar because I see this for new members a lot.

Comment: Could you give an example? It sounds like something that's specific to you, I don't have this problem.

Comment: Not broken here, either, I think this is something on your end.  Try nuking your browser cache.  If there is filtering on your network, then that could also interfere.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/590742/350004 silb avatar shows that.

Comment: it works in firefox not chromium

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any extensions installed that would block these? That is usually the case when an avatar won't load for me.  There are at least 3 avatar systems too, local SE hosted, gravatar, and facebook. It might not be immediately obvious which is being blocked.

Comment: @Seth: yes you are right it is some xtension; I tried in a guest session and no problem. sorry. hsould I close the issue ?

Comment: @solsTiCe No you should post this as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what's giving you the broken link image, I use NoScript and Disconnect in Firefox and silb's avatar won't display here either. I selected *inspect this element* from the context menu and found that his avatar is hosted on Facebook. Enabling Facebook in Disconnect made the avatar show up.